# List view using stream for image decoding

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a list view where every row contains an image coded in base64 so i use the from stream methode to decode them. At the first time when i access to my list the images are displayed correctly. But when i scroll down and rescroll to go up the app enters in break mode and tells me can not acces to closed stream i understand the problem but what is the solution to show all the images and scroll up and down without this problem.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to use `RetainElement` CacheStrategy for your listview, what happenes is that when you use the Recycle strategy , it destroys the stream when the item is not seen anymore.

Comment: public async void getannounc()
{   var an = await myservices.GetM();
    var a = an.getMResult;
 var l = new List<ImageSource> { };
for(int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++){
 var wo = a[i];        
 var byteArray = Convert.FromBase64String(ch);
 var stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
 var img = ImageSource.FromStream(() => stream);
 l.Add(img); 
}
mylist.ItemsSource = l; }

Comment: the code is working fine the problem is when i scroll and go back to see first elements again

Comment: I understand, I was more thinking of the whole project so I can play with , 
anyway check this one out https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading 
I think this is used in most apps  nowadays

Comment: i couldn't make a circle image with this

Comment: I found how to make a circle image but the problem stills the same

Comment: really strange , maybe you can share your code  in a repository so I can have a look